# GPS Location Is Enabled but Cant Find the Coordinates

Tags: android, gps

I use the Below code to get the Long Lat and its works fine when GPS location is on. But Issue is. when i turned Off the GPS location and then turn it On again. It didnt Show me the Any Log Lat.

```
public class GetGPSlocation implements LocationListener {
Context context;
public GetGPSlocation(Context c) {
    context = c;
}
public Location getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Permision Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPSenabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isGPSenabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 10, this);
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return l;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enable GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

i use this code on button CLick Listner...

```
     btnSaveAttd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GetGPSlocation g = new GetGPSlocation(v.getContext());
                Location l = g.getLocation();
                if (l!=null){
                    LAT = l.getLatitude();
                    LON = l.getLongitude();
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Call this doctor?\n\n" +
                                        "DocID: " +DocID.getText().toString()+ "\n"+
                                        "EmpName: " + empName.getText().toString() + "\n"+
                                        "DateTime: " + date +"\n" +
                                        "Time: "+time+"\n"+
                                        "Status : " + spinner.getSelectedItem()+"\n"+
                                        "Location: "+LON +" , " +LAT);
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                //endregion
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();

           }
        });
```

And Any one can tell me is there any way to enable GPS location automatically if GPS is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to changes of providers (i.e GPS) using Broadcast Receiver:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiverCallback, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiverCallback = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            // Do whatever you want here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Didnt get your answer.

Comment: There are many providers which provides location such as: GPS, Wifi, Fused... When users turn on/off location, it means they are turning on/off providers
The idea is to listen to any changes of these providers.